# Angular Unit Test Factory .catch()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm unit testing a factory for a 400 response and I don't understand why the .catch() response in the test case is undefined. The test is failing when the promise is chained with .catch() because the response is undefined but succeeds if .then() is used. Why is this $q.reject() response not passed to the .catch() function? I see that the .catch() block in the factory is receiving the $.reject() but when the response is returned in the unit test .catch is undefined.

***factory***

```
function resetTempPassword(data) {
  return $http.post('/reset_temp_password', data)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('inside then');
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  })
  .catch(function(response) {
    console.log('inside catch');
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
}
```

***test***

describe('resetTempPassword()', function() {
    var result;

```
beforeEach(function() {
  // init local result
  result = {};
  ...

it('should return 400 when called with invalid temp password', function() {
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('/reset_temp_password', RESET_TEMP_INVALID).respond(400, RESET_TEMP_ERROR);
  $httpBackend.whenPOST(API, RESET_TEMP_INVALID).respond(400, $q.reject(RESET_TEMP_ERROR));

  expect(idmAdminFactory.resetTempPassword).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(result).toEqual({});

  idmAdminFactory.resetTempPassword(RESET_TEMP_INVALID)
  .catch(function(response) {
    result = response;
  });
  // flush pending HTTP requests
  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect(idmAdminFactory.resetTempPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith(RESET_TEMP_INVALID);
  expect(result.data.code).toEqual(40008); // result.data is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think catch is part of the standard $http object. Then can have a second function parameter that's called when the $http call fails. I think that's what you should be using here:

```
function resetTempPassword(data) {
  return $http.post('/reset_temp_password', data)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('inside then');
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  },
  function(response) {
    console.log('inside catch');
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
}
```